# How to unselect a RadioButton?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Say I have some RadioButtons in a RadioButtonGroup. I click one of them and I realize I should not submit the form, instead I just want to trigger a cancel action and return to my original state of none selected. How can I do this?

Comment: Radio buttons require at least one to be checked if validated properly. Maybe you should use checkboxes instead? Or have one of the radio buttons with the option 'none'?

Comment: Yes, I have seen someone emulating RadioButtons with CheckButtons on another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150254/radiobuttongroup-within-nested-list

I might go this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I was incorrectly passing the value as the `defaultSelected` prop instead of `valueSelected`. Now if need to unselect, I can just pass `null` as the `valueSelected` prop.